# Is there a way in powershell to select what info needs to be the header so i can construct it to a table

Tags: powershell

I want to have a script that i can start and it gives me all the groups starting with APS- and its members

I want to get a HTML where it says in  the Header : the group  and in the table the Users

this is the code i got so far :

```
$properties = 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'UserPrincipalName'
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "APS-*"} | ForEach {
$groupName = $_.Name
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.SamAccountName |Get-ADUser -Property $properties |Select 
@{N='GroupName';E={$groupName}},'GivenName', 'Surname', 'UserPrincipalName'}
```

But this give me a list of  group,givenname,Surename,userprincipal

i want to get :
[Organized like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xzFA.png)

Is there a way of getting this ?

Comment: @mahmoud Moawad Yeah this gets me where i want to be , it shows all users in a HTML even the Admin's is there a way to exclude users from getting in the HTML ?

I was trying with :

-Exclude 44713.SamAccountName

Comment: yes, you can filter the output of `Get-ADGroupMember` to exclude the needed users, please check the reply below i modified it with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please consider the following points in order to accomplish the needed result

1. the variable `$properties` contains common values, you do not need to pass it to `Get-ADUser to get its values
2. You need to specify the parameter `recursive` to the command `Get-ADGroupMember` in order to get all child users within child groups.
3. If you need to output the result in HTML format you can use the command `ConvertTo-Html`

I modified your code to output the needed format, please check it

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "APS-*"}
$list = foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $groupName = $group.Name
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.SamAccountName -Recursive | Get-ADUser | select @{N='GroupName';E={$groupName}},'GivenName', 'Surname', 'UserPrincipalName'
        }
$out = $list | Group-Object GroupName 
[string]$out_html = foreach ($item in $out){
$item.group | Select-Object 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'UserPrincipalName' | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent "<br>$($item.Name)<br><br>"
}
$out_html| Out-File .\groups.html
```

if you need to exclude specific users from the report, you can filter the output of  `Get-ADGroupMember` using the `Where` clause as follow

```
# i.e. to exclude specific samaccountnames
$execlusionList = @("SamAccountName1","SamAccountName2") 
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.SamAccountName -Recursive | where {$_.samaccountname -notin $execlusionList} | Get-ADUser | select @{N='GroupName';E={$groupName}},'GivenName', 'Surname', 'UserPrincipalName'
```

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` can also return objects of type `group` or `computer` so you cannot pipe directly to `Get-ADUser`. Put a `Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' }` in between. Also, looking at the image, the OP wants output in Excel rather than HTML

Comment: I used the`-recursive` option with the `Get-ADGroupMember` and this doesn't return groups.

Comment: You are right according to the image, it's formatted as excel, but he also said that he wants `HTML where it says in the Header : the group and in the table the Users`

Comment: Yes, kinda unclear indeed..

Comment: couldn't get it here as a HTML  table sorry about that but its correct i need a HTML